# Objective C: updating values for key for an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-lion, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary with keys and values set up initially. 
Later I need to update the values for certain keys, and I thought I would just need to do 
[mutableDict setValue:val forKey:key], but this throws an exception saying:

```
[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

What am I doing wrong?
(I have another mutable dictionary inside each key of the mutable dictionary, but I don't think that's why)

Comment: For some reason you are actually working with an `NSDictionary` not an `NSMutableDictionary`. Hard to say why without more code, maybe you are using a copy obtained by calling `copy` or you have loaded the dictionary from a plist/userDefaults.. Can we see some more code?

Comment: @Paul.s Yes, I did copy an NSMutableDictionary. Would that be why? If it is, then what else should I use to copy?

Comment: Use `mutableCopy` instead of `copy` to get a mutable dictionary

Comment: @Paul.s oh.. didn't know about that. I'm new to Objective-C and I tried to search for what I am doing wrong but I missed it :( Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll copy an paste my comment just incase you want to keep your 100% accept

Paul.s

> For some reason you are actually working with an NSDictionary not an NSMutableDictionary. Hard to say why without more code, maybe you are using a copy obtained by calling copy or you have loaded the dictionary from a plist/userDefaults.. Can we see some more code?

Dennis

> @Paul.s Yes, I did copy an NSMutableDictionary. Would that be why? If it is, then what else should I use to copy?

Paul.s

> Use mutableCopy instead of copy to get a mutable dictionary

Dennis

> @Paul.s oh.. didn't know about that. I'm new to Objective-C and I tried to search for what I am doing wrong but I missed it :( Thank you!!